# Have TFS close tasks after code is deployed

Tags: deployment, tfs, build

In TFS 2012, there are "To Do", "In Progress", and "Done" columns on the board. I'd like to make two changes. First, add a new column called "Ready for Deployment" between "In Progress" and "Done". Second, have TFS set tasks in this column to "Done" when they are included in a build that finishes successfully. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure this is possible, but not how the standard process template is intended to be used. Normally you'd add a "Deploy" task under the PBI/UserStory/Requirement, if deployment of teh item is required. Then, when all other tasks are completed, you do the deployment and if that succeeds you close the parent Requirement work item.

That said, as long as you're not using Visual Studio Online, [you can edit the process template of any TFS process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243849%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add as many states are you desire. Keep in mind that if you're using Reports, that these might break due to the additional states you'll introduce. This will require you to update the reports (and the standard work item queries and Excel reports) as well.

The [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) can be used to [customize the process template in a graphical editor](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/09/09/process-template-customization.aspx), which is usually easier than manipulating the WIT-templates manually.

Alternatively, [if you're using TFS 2012 update 3 or later, you can add custom columns to the Product Backlog Board and use those instead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/03/13/10399287.aspx).

Comment: Adding custom columns to the Product Backlog Board seems like it'd be the easiest, but what about getting the build to set the tasks to done? I should have mentioned earlier that we associate each changeset to one or more tasks. Is there a way for the build to get the list of associated tasks and set them to "Done" if they are in my new "Ready for Deployment" column?

Comment: Not using the standard Build Activities. You could code a custom activity to do that usign the TFS Client Object Model. In that case the KanBan columns are not the easiest to use, since those are not yet easily accessible using the client object model. They're stored in a special field that has the following format: `{GUID}.kanban.column`